# C# Class preview not available in Solutions Explorer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have an issue with several of the C# files in my project.

When I click on the arrow next to the file name in the Solutions Explorer pane, the arrow disappears. For the rest of the files, clicking on the arrow unfolds a list of the classes inside the file. Also, when I open the file, the Project Dropdown under the file tabs shows "Miscellaneous Files" instead of the project name.

I have tried removing and re adding the files to the project, as well as closing and reopening Visual Studio.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by the `Build Action` being set to `None` instead of `Compile`

There are two ways two do it:

1. Select the file in the Solution Explorer pane. Click on the `Build Action`
   dropdown in the properties pane, and select `Compile`
2. Open your .csproj, find the line that says `<None Include="filename.cs" />` and change it to `<Compile Include="filename.cs" />`

Comment: Instead of opening the project's file does changing the `Generation Action` in the file properties from `None` to `Compile` works ?